# SimpleExoPlayer.Builder vs ExoPlayer.Builder Difference?

Tags: android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

What's the difference between SimpleExoPlayer.Builder vs ExoPlayer.Builder?

I didn't find much greater information about both these class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

class ExoPlayer diagram

```
public interface ExoPlayer
extends Player
```

An extensible media player that plays MediaSources. Instances can be obtained from `SimpleExoPlayer.Builder` or `ExoPlayer.Builder`.

but [SimpleExoPlayer](https://exoplayer.dev/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/SimpleExoPlayer.html)

```
public class SimpleExoPlayer
extends BasePlayer
```

implements `ExoPlayer`, `Player.AudioComponent`, `Player.VideoComponent`, `Player.TextComponent`, `Player.MetadataComponent`, `Player.DeviceComponent`

An [ExoPlayer](https://exoplayer.dev/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/ExoPlayer.html) implementation that uses default Renderer components. Instances can be obtained from SimpleExoPlayer.Builder.

For more information:

[SimpleExoPlayer.Builder](https://exoplayer.dev/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/SimpleExoPlayer.Builder.html)

[ExoPlayer.Builder](https://exoplayer.dev/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/ExoPlayer.Builder.html)

Answer (score 0):

`SimpleExoPlayer.Builder` comes with `DefaultRenderersFactory` that contain a lot of default value for video/audio streaming, where `ExoPlayer.Builder` comes without it

Comment: what is renderers?